# Short Story about a woman who loses her ring to a cleaning robot

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story I read was a sci-fi story when it was written, but now it would be considered normal everyday life, because we DO have cleaning robots.  So, this would date it.  Probably first written in the 60's or 70's.  What I read was probably a reprint put into book form with other short stories.  I read it in the mid to late 70's.

I don't think it was an Asimov story, but I am not sure about that.  It probably did appear in Asimov's magazine but was not likely written by him.  BUT!!! I could be wrong about that.

I am looking for a short story about a woman whose ring is sucked up by a cleaning robot and she has to get it back.

At the time it was a sci-fi story.  So, it has to be an old story.  I am looking through Asimov's lists of stories.  Possibly it was published in one of his magazines.  The cleaning robot sucks up or picks up the woman's ring.  It was her grandmother's ring or mother's ring.  The story has her racing around trying to stop the robot from discharging the dirt it has collected down the chute.

Even though this story would be considered normal by today's standards.  When it was written, humans could only dream of cleaning robots.  So, it must have been written in the 60's or 70's. Not sure.

It all takes place in her house/apartment.  She has her great grandmother's wedding ring.  She can't read the inscription on the ring.  something happens and she drops it on the floor.  And a little cleaning robot zips out of its cubbie and snaps it up.  It is heading back to the cubby.  She rushes over to block the cubby.  She tries to open the robot but can't.  She thinks about waiting for it to power down but that will be years.  She knows when it empties the debris goes into a massive recycling system.  I believe that she thinks about doing a lost and found service ticket but realizes that is not likely to work.  I think... she finally lets the robot go and gets on the phone and calls her mom to ask her what her great grandmother's name is.

I think I read it in a sci-fi anthology book in a series of anthologies like Asimov's stuff in the mid to late 70s.

Mine was a cheap book that contained multiple short stories.  It was not a magazine.  However, the story could have also appeared in a magazine.

I just need the name of the story and the author's name.  It was likely Asimov, but not sure.

Comment: Hi Bob. Cleaning robots aren't science fiction any more - you can buy them from Amazon! Was this a robot of the sort Asimov wrote about? If not can you clarify what makes the story science fiction?

Comment: I believe that I read this story in an old issue of Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine, in the late 1970s or early 1980s.

Comment: @JohnRennie - If a story was science fiction when it was written, and the futuristic technology in the story has become a reality, would that make the story now be off-topic here?  I wouldn't think so...

Comment: @Basya I didn't vote to close the question. I only asked that the OP clarify it. If the OP confirms Stanley's memory that it was published in Asimov I will vote to reopen.

Comment: This is a swell example of the dangers of AI/robots on a small scale.

Comment: Thanks Bob :-) With so much detail the story should be easy to find, but I've searched and searched with no luck. It certainly isn't in my collection though I don't have many copies of Asimov's . Maybe someone else will have more luck.